# Saving an Outlook.Mailitem as a file after it has been sent (c#)

Tags: c#, email, outlook

Based on [this issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d891c669-21af-4ce4-b24b-8f6eb2308227/knowing-when-a-specific-mail-item-has-been-sent?forum=vsto), I can save an Outlook.Mailitem object as a file when it is being sent:

```
..
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
...
public partial class MyClass: DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraUserControl
{
    static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem;
    ...    
    public static void SendAnOutlookMail()
    {
       ...
       mailItem.Display(false);
       ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Send += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(ThisAddIn_Send);
       ...
    };

    static void ThisAddIn_Send(ref bool Cancel)
    {
       mailItem.SaveAs(@"d:\1\sent.msg");
    }
    ...
}
```

My only problem is that the resulting file is an email in its state just *before* it has been sent (when I open it, I can press the send button on it).

My question: How could I save it in the *sent* state?

Comment: My guess: By retrieving it from the *Sent* folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the earliest you can access the item in its sent state and the sender information populated is in the `Items.ItemAdd` event handler on the Sent Items folder.

Comment: Thank, this solved my problem. I took the details from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515612/event-on-item-sent-in-outlook)