# Getting the actual sender's "sent items" folder in Office 365 Outlook (c#)

Tags: c#, email, outlook

My [earlier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062170/saving-an-outlook-mailitem-as-a-file-after-it-has-been-sent-c) about catching an email message just after it has sent was resolved by using the `Items.ItemAdd` event handler of the Sent Items folder. This works fine when I don't change the sender mailbox. But if I change it by selecting some other account from the dropdown list of the sender on the interface shown by `mailItem.Display(true);` , then the sent message lands in the "sent items" folder of this other account, but

```
Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
```

doesn't change accordingly, so in this way I can't catch the message. How could I get the "sent items" folder of the selected (not default) sender?
(an acceptable workaround would be to change the default mailbox, but I also don't know how to do this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/store-getdefaultfolder-method-outlook) method of the Store class returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

You can to handle the `ItemSend` event of the `Application` class where you can get the sender. Then you can find associated store and use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/store-getdefaultfolder-method-outlook) method to get the correct Sent Items folder.

Be aware, the [SaveSentMessageFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-savesentmessagefolder-property-outlook) property of the MailItem class returns or sets a Folder object that represents the folder in which a copy of the e-mail message will be saved after being sent (instead of the Sent Items folder).